# Eclipse - Link SVN to a subdirectory project of the checked out project

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

The project hierarchy structure is something like this:

```
ParentProjectBundle
    DBScripts
    ImptFiles
    Codes
       EclipseProject
          Project1
              build.xml
     build.xml
```

Now, I have checked out the ParentProjectBundle using tortoisesvn and have imported Project1 in Eclipse.  How can I link the svn for Project1?

Thanks!

Comment: There is SVN plug-in for eclipse. If you have that plug-in installed in your eclipse, It will link it automatically

Comment: @VikasSachdeva, no it's not working in the svn plug-in.